# Electron App throwing quit unexpectedly error message on Mac when quitting the app

Tags: javascript, macos, electron

I'm running into an issue with an electron app I'm building where I get a Problem report prompt from my mac when I quit the app (CMD+Q): "Electron quit unexpectedly". I get the same error message when I build the app for prod. The app isn't actually crashing or quitting unexpectedly.

The tricky part here is that I'm not able to replicate the error. There are occasions the problem report doesn't show up, but for some users it shows up every time (leading them to believe the app is crashing).

I've implemented quit in the following way:

```
menu.append(
  new MenuItem({
    label: 'Temp Str',
    submenu: [
      {
        role: 'quit',
        accelerator: process.platform === 'darwin' ? 'Cmd+Q' : 'Alt+f4',
        click: () => app.quit(),
      },
    ],
  }),
);
```

Any suggestions here on how I prevent the Problem Report for Electron error message from showing up when someone quits the app? It's pretty detrimental to the product because it leads users to believe that the app is crashing.

FWIW I've tested different MacOS versions, but have run into the same issue.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with a minimal repo like `electron-quick-start`?

Comment: Have you tried what happens if you reproduce the error on a windows machine?

Answer (score 0):

**Cause:**
This can happen when your electron app is still running code (not waiting for events) when the quit event occurs. If you have native libraries linked in, they can generate a fault such as an abort(), assertion failure, or SEGV when node tries to stop a thread that's currently calling into such a library.

**Diagnosing:**
You can learn more about the cause of your crash by clicking "Report" when the "unexpected" dialog appears, and then reading the text of the displayed crash report. It will say which thread crashed, and it will contain the current native call stack of every other thread. For me I was able to deduce that "libvips" (a native image processing dependency) contained internal assertion failures which caused the "unexpected" symptom.

**Solutions:**
You could avoid this problem by **(A)** removing the ill-behaved native dependency, or **(B)** by waiting for it to complete its work normally before exiting.

For **(A)**, if you have your choice of libraries, pick one that's pure Javascript, or one that handles interruptions more gracefully.

For **(B)**, you can delay Electron shutdown by hooking the "before-quit" event and preventing the default timing. Then in that handler you can do your own cleanup and then finish exiting. Here is a toy version of the code that worked for me in my app:

```
const {app} = require('electron');

let nativeWorkRunning = 0;
let isStopping = false;

app.on('before-quit', async e => {
   e.preventDefault();  // stops the quit from happening
   isStopping = true;
   while (nativeWorkRunning) {
     await sleep(100);  // wait for native work
   }
   app.exit();  // immediate exit
});

function myNativeFunction() {
  if (isStopping) {
    return false;  // don't let new native calls through
  }
  try {
    nativeWorkRunning++;
    my_native_module.do_whatever();
  } finally {
    nativeWorkRunning--;
  }
}

function sleep() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}
```